# Make an animated gif with imagemagick, it enlarge my image and put each frame in corner

Tags: animation, imagemagick

I want to make an animated gif from this frames .png image:

[image]

What I tried to do is resize it to a smaller image, split it into 4 parts, then make it animate. At first, I resize and split it with this command

```
mogrify -resize 140x140 -crop 2x2@ ps1.png
```

it seems worked well by returning 4 images, like this:

[image]

Now, I make them an animate gif with this:

```
convert -delay 25x100 -loop 0 ps1-*.png ps1.gif
```

But it returned this messed up image, instead of a cat crying:

[image]

Btw, When became an animated gif, the image seems more sharpen, is there anyway to prevent it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use imagemagick to make an animated gif and it's all messed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078796/trying-to-use-imagemagick-to-make-an-animated-gif-and-its-all-messed-up)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I thought the question is not detailed enough, so I make this. No one answered it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in each corner is coming from the image page offset. You can view this by running the generated frames against the `identify` utility.

```sh
identify ps1-*.png

# ps1-0.png PNG 70x46 140x92+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.24KB 0.000u 0:00.009
# ps1-1.png[1] PNG 70x46 140x92+70+0 8-bit sRGB 4.26KB 0.000u 0:00.000
# ps1-2.png[2] PNG 70x46 140x92+0+46 8-bit sRGB 4.39KB 0.000u 0:00.000
# ps1-3.png[3] PNG 70x46 140x92+70+46 8-bit sRGB 4.64KB 0.000u 0:00.000
#                        ^^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
```

To resolve that issue, simply remove the paging offset by running the extracted images through `+repage`.

```sh
 mogrify +repage ps1-*.png
```

For Animating the GIF, ensure that you specify how you want the [layers to be handled](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#layers). In this example, I believe you would want to optimize-frame or plus. [Dispose](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#dispose) & [coalesce](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#coalesce) can also be used to tweak the resulting animation.

```sh
convert -layers OptimizePlus -delay 25x100 ps1*.png -loop 0 ps1.gif
```

[image: Crying cat]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, the image's quality seems so low, is it possible to handle it?

Comment: The reduction in quality would be caused by the `-resize` & png-2- gif conversion. I'd recommend doing any resizing/scaling as the last step in this example. There's a great article on [Anti-Aliasing](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/) that may offer better details & solutions.

Comment: Could you be more detailed? I tried to put -resize to the last step but no luck. In the article, it seems like image would be sharpen after adding some parameter, but my image became sharpen without anything, and I don't want it. I do a search and found -quality, but it seems like imagemagick ignore -quality.